# What is the difference in implementation of different browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone please let me know the technical difference in implementation of different browser like Firefox, Chrome and IE webdriver in selenium webdriver??

Comment: They are different browsers??????

Comment: Google it, you can get more info. if you're concerned about any thing particular, detail it.

Comment: I feel like people doesn't understand the question maybe, if webdriver is a standard why do we need to instantiate different classes for each one of them. I am guessing they don't follow the standard yet but no idea about exact differences.

Answer (score 0):

Each driver is used to automate the application in that particular browser.

For example, if you use FirefoxDriver, your automation script will run in Firefox browser.

Technically their implementation is different and based on WebDriver interface.

Comment: so for running any web application in different browser we have to change the whole code??

Comment: no. you need to change which browser you want to use. not the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

`ChromeDriver`, `InternetExplorerDriver` and `FirefoxDriver` are implementation of [`WebDriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) interface. Each provides implementation corresponding to the appropriate browser.
You dont need to change the code when you change the browser. You can write the code using instance of `WebDriver` and  just change implementing object depending on the browser. 
Like if you are using Firefox

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("SOME_RANDOM_URL");
driver.find("SOME_RANDOM_ELEMENT");
```

if you want to change browser to chrome

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
// rest of the code will remain same
```

This is called [Programming to interfaces.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: This  sentence would be incorrect "You dont need to change the code when you change the browser."   Some of the WebDrivers do not implement all command so need to use different flow.  Question edited to mention this point.

Answer (score 0):

The code remains the same except for the driver instances and paths you will be specifying; As you would have already known, for firefox, you don't need to download any drivers explicitly. You just create the driver instance as below -

**a) Firefox -**

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

**b) IE -** 
For IE, you need to download IE driver and then place it in your drive. You then include the driver path in your code as follows (replace with your driver path in code below) -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

**c) Chrome -** 
For Chrome again, you need to download chrome driver and then place it in your drive. You then include the driver path in your code as follows (replace with your driver path in code below)-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```